# Show only one row of df in plotly stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I've got a pandas dataframe and I want to show one row of it as a stacked bar chart.
I managed to show all rows, but I jsut can't figure out, how to to only show ONE row.

this is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {"2020-11": -1, "2020-12": -2, '2021-01': -3}
df = pd.DataFrame({'category 0': data,
                   'category 2': data,
                   'category 3': data})

fig = px.bar(df,
             x=df.index,
             y=[c for c in df.columns],
             )
fig.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image: current figure]

This is what I actually want:

[image: desired figure]

what I tried:

```
fig = px.bar(df,
             x=df.loc["2020-12"],
             y=[c for c in df.columns],
             )
```

-> But then it stacks ALL rows together

```
fig = px.bar(df.loc["2020-12"],
             x=df.index,
             y=[c for c in df.columns],
             )
```

-> is totally wrong

and all other combinations I could think of.

Please help.

BONUS QUESTION:
How can I make, so that the bars go up instead of downwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {"2020-11": -1, "2020-12": -2, '2021-01': -3}
df = pd.DataFrame({'category 0': data,
                   'category 2': data,
                   'category 3': data})

# Filter Where Index is Desired Value
plot_df = df[df.index == '2020-12']

fig = px.bar(
    plot_df,
    x=plot_df.index,
    y=[c for c in df.columns],
)
fig.show()
```